# Regularity of a function by approximation by polynomials.

Tags: reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, reference-works

A standard argument says that a continous function is $ C^{k,\alpha} $ at zero if there exists a polinomial of degree k such that 
$$
| (u - P)(x)| \le C | x|^{k+\alpha}.
$$
This is the way for intance that Caffarelli does his interior estimates. Let $ k=2 $. We can see easilly that if $ u \in C^{2,\alpha} $ at zero. Then, the inequality above is satisfied with the constant $ C = \sup \{Du(x)\} $ and the polynomial 
$$
P(x) := u(0) + \langle Du(0), x \rangle + \dfrac{1}{2} x^t D^2u(0) x.
$$

Here I want to obtain the reciprocal. that is, is there exists a polynomial satisfying the above inequality then, $ u \in C^{2,\alpha} $ at zero. Well, we can see that
$$
u(x) := u(0) + \langle Du(0), x \rangle + \dfrac{1}{2} x^t D^2u(0) x + o(|x|^{2+ \alpha}). 
$$
Then, $ u \in C^2 $ at zero. Rest only to prove that its second derivatives are $ C^\alpha $ at zero. How to do this?

Comment: What does "$C^{k, \alpha}$ at zero" mean?

Comment: Does it mean that
$$
|Du(x) -Du(0)| \le C |x|^\alpha.
$$
for a universal constant C.

Comment: Regarding the "Well, we can see that...": No, we can't see that, because there's no reason to think that $D^2u(0)$ even _exists_.

Comment: But 
$$
 \dfrac{|u(x) - P(x)|}{|x|^2} \le c |x|^{\alpha} \rightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{as} \quad |x| \rightarrow 0.
$$
doen't imply that $ D^2u(0)= C  $ where
$$
P(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} x^t Cx + \langle b, x \rangle + a.
$$

Answer (score 1):

"Standard argument"? What you claim is false.

If true, then, taking $P=0$, it would follow that if $|u(x)|\le x^2$ then $u$ is better than $C^1$ at $0$. Define $$u(x)=\begin{cases}x^4,&(x\in\Bbb Q),
\\0,&(x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q).\end{cases}$$

Then $|u(x)|\le x^4$, but $u'$ has no chance of being continuous at the origin, since it's not even *defined* in any neighborhood of the origin.

(Possibly Caffarelli is very confused, or possibly he actually has some stronger hypothesis that you missed.)

**Edit** Now the OP says he forgot to say that $u$ is continuous. That doesn't help, the counterexample is just a little more intricate: Let $$u(x)=\begin{cases}x^4\sin(1/x^{10}),&(x\ne0),
\\0,&(x=0).\end{cases}$$

Then $u$ is continuous, $|u(x)|\le x^4$, and $u$ is differentiable everywhere, but $u'$ is not continuous at the origin.

There simply is no such result - no rate of decay implies that $u'$ is continuous at the origin.

Comment: In fact, I forgot that $u$ must be continuous. You can think the function defined in $B_1$.

Comment: @user29999 That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Then, give a counterexample, please.

Comment: @user29999 What??? There's a counterexample in my answer. (Maybe you're still seeing the previous version? If so there should be a link saying it's been edited...)